# Show tooltip in LineSeries WinForms Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am working on a Dashboard System where i am using Line Chart in WinForms. I need to show the tooptip on each line. I have tried this

```
var series = new Series
                    {
                        Name = chartPoint.SetName,
                        Color = chartPoint.ChartColor,
                        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
                        BorderDashStyle = chartPoint.ChartDashStyle,
                        BorderWidth = chartPoint.BorderWidth,
                        IsVisibleInLegend = !chartPoint.HideLegend,
                        ToolTip = "Hello World"
                    };
```

but its not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some RnD i got tooltips on Line Series, but still confused why its not working with this solution. 
Here is the solution

```
series.ToolTip = string.Format("Name '{0}' : X - {1} , Y - {2}", chartPoint.SetName, "#VALX{F2}",
                                               "#VALY{F2}");
        mainChartControl.GetToolTipText += ChartControlGetToolTipText;

 private void ChartControlGetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two options either use `Keywords` accepted by the Chart control.

```
myChart.Series[0].ToolTip = "Name #SERIESNAME : X - #VALX{F2} , Y - #VALY{F2}";
```

In the `Chart` control, a `Keyword` is a character sequence that is replaced with an automatically calculated value at run time. For a comprehensive list of keywords accepted by the Chart control look up [Keyword reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx)
or

if you want something more fanciful, you have to handle the event `GetToolTipText`

```
this.myChart.GetToolTipText += new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.ToolTipEventHandler(this.myChart_GetToolTipText);
```

Now I am not sure what you want to show on the ToolTip but you could add the logic accordingly. Assuming you want to show the values of the `DataPoints` in the series

```
private void myChart_GetToolTipText(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType)
    {  
        case ChartElementType.DataPoint:
            e.Text = myChart.Series[0].Points[e.HitTestResult.PointIndex]).ToString()
                     + /* something for which no keyword exists */;
            break;
        case ChartElementType.Axis:
            // add logic here
        case ....
        .
        .    
        default:
            // do nothing       
    }
```

Comment: @ ravi, did this not help you ??